# Kernel trying to load nonexistent firmware

Tags: debian, kernel, firmware, iwlwifi

I am getting the following errors in my `dmesg`

```
[    4.740447] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwl-dbg-cfg.ini (-2)
[    4.740615] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-cc-a0-57.ucode (-2)
[    4.740736] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-57.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.740754] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-cc-a0-56.ucode (-2)
[    4.740847] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-56.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.745316] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwl-debug-yoyo.bin (-2)
```

Here is the full output of `dmeg | grep fail`:

```
[    4.463423] nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    4.533570] iTCO_wdt: probe of iTCO_wdt failed with error -16
[    4.683597] platform regulatory.0: firmware: failed to load regulatory.db (-2)
[    4.683786] platform regulatory.0: Direct firmware load for regulatory.db failed with error -2
[    4.683787] cfg80211: failed to load regulatory.db
[    4.740447] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwl-dbg-cfg.ini (-2)
[    4.740615] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-cc-a0-57.ucode (-2)
[    4.740736] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-57.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.740754] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-cc-a0-56.ucode (-2)
[    4.740847] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-56.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.745316] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwl-debug-yoyo.bin (-2)
[    5.034328] thermal thermal_zone13: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
```

I did some looking around on https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/iwlwifi/backport-iwlwifi.git/
to see if I could find the missing firmware, but it appears it doesn't exist.

`uname -a` reads: `Linux IBUKI 4.19.0-9-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.118-2+deb10u1 (2020-06-07) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

I'm honestly not sure what to do, please help!

Comment: What card is this, an Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX200?

Answer (score 1):

If the effect of this is nothing more than log entries, I wouldn't worry about it. The firmware is for 3000, 4000, 5000 and 6000 series Intel wifi laptop adapters. If wifi isn't working, install the iwlwifi package. In Debian it is non-free, so you have to edit 'etc/apt/sources.list' and put 'non-free' after 'main contrib' in the repository lines.

deb http://debian.repository/debian/ buster main contrib non-free

But make it like 'your' system. My line is just an example.

Answer (score 1):

Intel directly contributes code to Linux WiFi drivers, so sometimes the contributed code may include references to Intel's own firmware debugging tools:

```
firmware: failed to load iwl-dbg-cfg.ini (-2)
firmware: failed to load iwl-debug-yoyo.bin (-2)
```

... or to firmware versions that have never been publicly released outside Intel:

```
firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-cc-a0-57.ucode (-2)
Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-57.ucode failed with error -2
firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-cc-a0-56.ucode (-2)
Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-56.ucode failed with error -2
```

The [linux-firmware Git repository](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/) has `iwlwifi-cc-a0-59.ucode` and `iwlwifi-cc-a0-55.ucode`, so the versions between those have either been never released, or have been withdrawn from public distribution, probably because they were tested internally by Intel and were found to be buggy.

```
platform regulatory.0: firmware: failed to load regulatory.db (-2)
platform regulatory.0: Direct firmware load for regulatory.db failed with error -2
```

On the other hand, these messages indicate you don't currently have the Debian package `wireless-regdb` installed.

Note that the current versions of the package contain two versions of the regulatory database: one is signed by Debian, the other by the upstream Linux kernel developer responsible for the WiFi regulatory subsystem.

If you use a Debian kernel, you should use the default Debian-signed version; if you use a upstream/mainline kernel you've built yourself, you should use `update-alternatives --config regulatory.db` to switch to the upstream version, as the upstream kernel won't be able to validate Debian's signature.